# How to check internet connection enabled or disabled in Espresso for Android

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my application have a button that will be enabled or disabled based on internet connection so how can I write Espresso code for checking internet connection in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the same as usually.

You will need appropriate `Context` for getting `ConnectivityManager`. If you are using [`ActivityTestRule`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html) in your `Espresso` tests, then just pass:

```
mActivityTestRule.getActivity()
```

to the method, that checks connection status.

Sample code:

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Usage:

```
assertTrue(isConnected(mActivityTestRule.getActivity()));
```